# RStudio server on AWS has a white screen, can't access data to remove .RData/.RHistory

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, rstudio-server

I have been running an RStudio Server for a few months and when I tried to login again it gave me a white screen (after the login page). I can't access the code or files on the AWS instance.

I am happy to install a fresh RStudio server but I would like to access the files (before I was accessing them through RStudio file manager.

I have tried connecting to the instance online but I get the following error.

[image]

I have tried many things but nothing seems to have worked.

In session manager I get the following:

```
We weren't able to connect to your instance. Common reasons for this include:
SSM Agent isn't installed on the instance. You can install the agent on both Windows instances and Linux instances.
The required IAM instance profile isn't attached to the instance. You can attach a profile using AWS Systems Manager Quick Setup.
Session Manager setup is incomplete. For more information, see Session Manager Prerequisites.
```

I also have not been able to SSH into my instance. I have tried creating pem files to try and access it, changing permissions and security groups but I can't seem to acess it. In my terminal I have the following error:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for 'id_rsa.pub.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "id_rsa.pub.pem": bad permissions
ubuntu@ec2-35-181-152-160.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

After running: `ssh -i "id_rsa.pub.pem" ubuntu@ec2-00-000-000-000.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com`

EDIT 1:

I get the following:

```
(base) bscuser@localhost:myfolder/s3_AWS/s3_AWS> chmod 600 id_rsa.pub.pem
(base) bscuser@localhost:myfolder/s3_AWS> ssh -i "id_rsa.pub.pem" ubuntu@ec2-00-000-000-000.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for 'id_rsa.pub.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "id_rsa.pub.pem": bad permissions
ubuntu@ec2-00-000-000-00.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
(base) bscuser@localhost:myfolder/s3_AWS/s3_AWS>
```

Comment: It seems that your private key is readable by others. Try `chmod 600 id_rsa.pub.pem` then try again.

Comment: I tried that and get the same message

Comment: To be clear: the perms on the file were previously `0644`, and you get the *"are too open"* problem. You `chmod 600 id_rsa.pub.pem` on the file, and you still get the *"are too open"* problem? Is `myfolder/s3_AWS` a local filesystem or mounted somehow (e.g., sshfs)? Is it linux/macos native (e.g., ext4), windows ntfs (on a wsl mount), or something else?

Comment: I am using OpenSUSE. The folder is mounted on a memory pen in the following location `/run/media/bscuser/A34E-C6B8/inmobiliarioProject2/s3_AWS`

Comment: When I transfer the pem/pub files to my desktop I get the same error.

Comment: "memory pen" ... it seems highly likely that it is a windows-friendly filesystem such as FAT32 or NTFS. Neither of which support the perms you need (in a way that `ssh` understands). Don't run off of a pen, copy it into a local filesystem (that is native-linux, e.g., `ext4`), change the perms of the file and its enclosing directory, and try again. The popular/preferred location would be `${HOME}/.ssh/`, where the `.ssh` directory is perms 700 and the files (at least the key) are `600`.